# Why Steppenwolf instead of Darkseid?

Tags: character, production, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

In the recent movie *Justice League*, the villain of this part was Steppenwolf. I had previously heard rumors about Darkseid being the villain. (Maybe he'll come in the second installment)

So,

- Why was Steppenwolf brought first as the villain before Darkseid? Is he Darkseid's commander or something?
- He mentioned Darkseid's name in one of his *speeches*, what is his relation with Darkseid? *(considering the speech in which he mentioned Darkseid he also mentions his mother, so I was thinking maybe there's some family relationship)*

Comment: In comics Steppenwolf is Darkseid's uncle.

Comment: huh. so first the uncle came to make it easier for his nephew to conquer the world? weird :D

Comment: If I am not wrong even in comics Darkseid is stronger then Steppenwolf but in film there relation not really mentioned and few unsourced claim said he is his son in film universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why was Steppenwolf brought first as the villain before Darkseid? Is he Darkseid's commander or something?

[Steppenwolf](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Steppenwolf_(Prime_Earth)) is Darkseid's most powerful ally and a [new God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Gods). He is the leader of his army(parademons and others). He is brought before Darkseid so as to mark the beginning of Darkseid's invasion on Earth, when Darkseid himself would come to fight the Justice League. (see [Justice League War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War))

---

> He mentioned Darkseid's name in one of his speeches, what is his relation with Darkseid?

- [Steppenwolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steppenwolf_(comics)) is Darkseid's uncle. When Darkseid kills his own mother, he resurrects Steppenwolf, he made Steppenwolf the commander of his military.

---

Read this for some insights : http://comicbook.com/dc/2017/11/21/justice-league-history-of-earth-vs-apokolips-explained/

---

**SPOILER**

Steppenwolf is powerful, he kills Wonder Woman in DC-New 52 Earth 2.

[image]